# Google cloud speech API response : Parsing iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to integrate google cloud speech API in my demo app.
What I am getting as result is below :

```
    {
    results {
      alternatives {
        transcript: "hello"
      }
      stability: 0.01
    }
}
```

Code to get response :

```
[[SpeechRecognitionService sharedInstance] streamAudioData:self.audioData
                                                withCompletion:^(StreamingRecognizeResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
                                                    _textView.text = [error localizedDescription];
                                                    [self stopAudio:nil];
                                                  } else if (response) {
                                                    BOOL finished = NO;
                                                    //NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", response.resultsArray);
                                                    for (StreamingRecognitionResult *result in response.resultsArray) {
                                                        NSLog(@"result : %@",result);
                                                        //_textView.text = result.alternatives.transcript;
                                                      if (result.isFinal) {
                                                        finished = YES;
                                                      }
                                                    }

                                                    if (finished) {
                                                      [self stopAudio:nil];
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                                }
     ];
```

My problem is, the response i am getting is not a proper JSON then how do i get the value of key `transcript` ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you post some code that how are you sending request and receiving response?

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIORadded. I am using there demo code they have provide on their site.

Comment: Hi, I am facing problem in installation of libraries for streaming Google Speech. I installed app libs and copied Google folder. Can you guide me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871015/error-posting-to-clearcut-null-with-status-code-400-in-google-cloud-speech?noredirect=1#comment76721628_44871015

Comment: why copy sample folder ? just add pod name and install it your project. Or tell me more about that. Like your project structure and code. @WasimSafdar

Comment: What is pod name? Because I am using path "  pod 'googleapis', :path => '.'
" in pod file and that's why copying this. I tried to find pod name but could not find in documentation available.

Comment: @WasimSafdar googleapis is the pod name. so after installing pod what are you doing ?

Comment: @WasimSafdar Also show me your code. it is not possible to debug your problem like this.

Comment: After installing, I just run the code and it shows memory error. Error occurs in my another project not in the project that is available on Github.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151138/discussion-between-sharad-chauhan-and-wasimsafdar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone who is looking for this problem's solution:

```
for (StreamingRecognitionResult *result in response.resultsArray) {
    for (StreamingRecognitionResult *alternative in result.alternativesArray) {
        _textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[alternative valueForKey:@"transcript"]];
    }
    if (result.isFinal) {
        finished = YES;
    }
}
```

This is what i did to get the value for `transcript` continuously.

Comment: Has anyone parsed it in swift? I am facing subscript member error when trying to get "transcript" value. Please help.for alternative in result.alternativesArray {
                                        if let alternative = alternative as? StreamingRecognitionResult {
                                            textView.text = "\(alternative["transcript"])"
                                        }
                                    }

Comment: @tania_S Same problem here. It seems this answer's syntax doesn't work anymore with Swift4.

Comment: @Josh may be. I never had a chance to do this in swift.

Comment: @tania_S I got the solution to this question running with Swift 4, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that will solve your problem on Swift4/iOS11.2.5, enjoy!:

```
SpeechRecognitionService.sharedInstance.streamAudioData(audioData, completion:
{ [weak self] (response, error) in
    guard let strongSelf = self else {
        return
    }
    if let error = error {
        print("*** Streaming ASR ERROR: "+error.localizedDescription)
    } else if let response = response {
        for result in response.resultsArray {
            print("result i: ")  //log to console
            print(result)
            if let alternative = result as? StreamingRecognitionResult {
                for a in alternative.alternativesArray{
                    if let ai = a as? SpeechRecognitionAlternative{
                        print("alternative i: ")  //log to console
                        print(ai)
                        if(alternative.isFinal){
                            print("*** FINAL ASR result: "+ai.transcript)
                            strongSelf.stopGoogleStreamingASR(strongSelf)
                        }
                        else{
                            print("*** PARTIAL ASR result: "+ai.transcript)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            else{
                print("ERROR: let alternative = result as? StreamingRecognitionResult")
            }
        }
    }
})
```