# Error posting to Clearcut: (null), with Status Code: 400 in Google Cloud Speech API

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I want to use Google Cloud Speech API in one of my app. I want to use Cloud Speech Streaming gRPC. I am using following sample as an example. [Cloud Speech Streaming gRPC Objective-C Sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Objective-C/Speech-gRPC-Nonstreaming)

I installed this demo application and it is working fine but when I installed required Google Speech libs in my application and tried to run my application, my application crashed with above mentioned error. 
[image]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I used the code given in sample application. This error occurs just after installing important libraries.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am getting a crash and created issue on Git. If you help me, I shall be very much thankful to you. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/issues/46

Answer (score 2):

I removed Firebase/Core from pod file and also removed it's headers in the files where I am using solved my problem. If you face this problem just update your pod files with latest version of Firebase.