# Accessing Google Cloud speech-to-text response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition

I am a total beginner with this and I hope someone can point me into the right direction: I used the Google Cloud Speech-to-text API, in particular the longrunningrecognize method. Now everything works out and I get the expected results:

```
{
  "name": "4983661747957213554",
  "metadata": {
    "@type": 
"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata",
    "progressPercent": 100,
    "startTime": "2019-04-07T10:22:26.018723Z",
    "lastUpdateTime": "2019-04-07T10:23:17.659732Z"
  },
  "done": true
}
```

After this have been stuck for a full day though. The transcription is done, but how do I access it? Which variable can I call to see the result? How can I save it to a file?
On top, I am wondering what´s the best way to run Python scripts in GCP.

I have seen this answer: [Google cloud speech API response : Parsing iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062099/google-cloud-speech-api-response-parsing-ios)
but it brings me to a very fundamental problem that I am experiencing: How and where is the best way to execute that code?

I have also tried to create *.py files and chmod them, but is there any easier way to run simple scripts?

My expected result is the final text file or even just access to a string that is behind the operations: that I get returned.

Answer (score 0):

Google has examples in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-protocol):

In shell, you can run

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/4983661747957213554"
```

Where 4983661747957213554 is the name of your operation returned above. And it will print you the results:

```
{
  "name": "7612202767953098924",
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata",
    "progressPercent": 100,
    "startTime": "2017-07-20T16:36:55.033650Z",
    "lastUpdateTime": "2017-07-20T16:37:17.158630Z"
  },
  "done": true,
  "response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse",
    "results": [
      {
        "alternatives": [
          {
            "transcript": "okay so what am I doing here...(etc)...",
            "confidence": 0.96096134,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
```

In Python you can run the [demo script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/transcribe_async.py).